# Javascript and PHP JSON Asynchronous Request Error

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I am always catching errors when sending an async request from my client-side javascript to my web-service php code. No guarantee that I used those terms correctly but I tried. It always catches an error and I think that the php code is not even being called.

```
function suggestSearch() {
     var value = document.getElementById("filterText").value; //Suchtext
     let reqObj = {method: "getNames", input: value};
     fetch("actions/async_search.php", {method:"POST",body:JSON.stringify(reqObj)})
      .then((response) => {
           if(response.ok) {
                let contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
                if(contentType && contentType.indexOf("application/json") != -1) {
                     return response.json();
                }
            }
            throw new Error("Error in response!");
      })
      .then((result) => {
           for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                 var obj = result[i];
                 console.log(obj.id);
           }
       })
       .catch( (error) => { alert("An error occured!" + error);
       })
}
```

async_search.php:

```php
 header("Content-Type: application/json");
    $result = ["result" => null];

    $request = file_get_contents("php://input");

    if(isset($request) && !empty($request)) {
        $requestObj = json_decode($request);
        if($requestObj->method == "getNames") {
            $input = $requestObj->input;
            if($input != "") {
                $sql = "SELECT ArtikelName FROM artikel WHERE ArtikelName LIKE ? LIMIT 5;"; 
                $statement = $conn -> prepare($sql); //prepare
                $statement -> execute(array("$input%")); 
                $result = $statement -> fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                echo json_encode($result);

            }
        }
    }
```

**// EDIT :** 
Now I came so far that I get this as an error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: That `JSON.parse` error hints that there may be non-json output from your PHP. Are you outputting anything else on the page? Are any errors being echoed from your PHP?

Comment: @frobinsonj everything you see (except the sql connection part which I didn't include, but I can assure is fully working) is the full php file. I am not outputting anything else on the async_search.php page. I am also not getting any errors from the PHP itself

Comment: How does the response look like? Did you checked the output in the inspector?
Edit: For the "else" case for "if(isset($request) && !empty($request)) { ... }" the response will be empty which could cause the JSON.parse error

Comment: @mrak yea I checked the inspector it said undefined at line 84 which is "console.log(obj.id);" which is in the code block with the .then(result) - so I guess you are right, the response is empty, do you have any idea how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error. When saving to the $result array I have to put the variables in brackets, e.g.

```
$result = ["result" => ($row['ArtikelName']), "info" => "Ok"];
```

before encoding it. I hope this helps someone in the future.